# Saving output to file using pycurl?

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I'm using pycurl to fetch a jpg from a server,  how would I go about saving this to a file?

I can't see an option to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to write the file yourself, here is an example:

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://my.server/a.jpg')
with open('o.jpg', 'w') as f:
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, f.write)
    c.perform()
```

Comment: I am doing the same:

     c = pycurl.Curl()
        fileOprurl = str(location)
        print("URL : ",fileOprurl)
        out="output_filename.txt"
    
        c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER,['x-api-key: %s' %str(api_key)])
        c.setopt(pycurl.URL, fileOprurl)
    
        with open(out, "wb") as f:
            c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, f.write())
            c.perform()
    
        c.close()
        f.close()

But output file `output_filename.txt` is blank. Input file is not blank.